# Using reference passed from different cpp file in native code gives segmentation fault

Tags: gdb, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I've tried this : calling a function (with parameter reference) from  another cpp file, I can't assign anything to the parameter passed by reference.

in a function Java_com_example_afeTest_testReference in test.cpp

```
std::string a ="";
const std::string x = "jo";
std::string y = "yi", z = "ta";
testFunc(a,x,y, z);           // call test function which resides in same cpp no error
```

Now put this function in test.cpp it works

```
std::string& testFunc(std::string& a, const std::string& x, std::string& y, std::string& z){
    a = x;
    a +=y;
    a +=z;

    return a;
}
```

Now put this testFunc in a different test2.cpp & call it from test.cpp it will produce segmentation fault after
a=x

** So if testFunc & Java_com_example_afeTest_testReference  is same cpp file it works, if two functions in two cpp files and you want to pass reference, it gives segmentation fault. I've checked with extern also.

Comment: calling a function (with parameter reference) from  another cpp file, I can't assign anything to the parameter passed by reference.
in a function Java_com_example_afeTest_testReference in test.cpp

    std::string a ="";
    const std::string x = "jo";
std::string y = "yi", z = "ta";
testFunc(a,x,y, z);

Now put this function in test.cpp it works
std::string& testFunc(std::string& a, const std::string& x, std::string& y, std::string& z){
 a = x;
 a +=y;
 a +=z;
 return a;
}

Now put this testFunc in a different test2.cpp & call it from test.cpp it will produce segmentation fault after
a=x

Comment: Does it only happen with strings? What happens if you replace your std::string with int? Are you getting any compiler warnings? Have you made any significant changes to Android.mk or Application.mk? You might try setting `APP_STL := stlport_static` in your Application.mk -- It's what I use and I've not had these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used gnustl_static. It doesn't support reference passing from one shared library to another shared library and was giving segmentation fault. This works when they are in the same library.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to modify the contents of the original const string. This can't be a good idea. Casting away the constness of the data() return value is nasty too. Whether or not that is the cause of your segfault, I'm not sure. In any case, try this:

```
string tolower(const string& str){
    size_t iSize = str.size();
    string result = str;    
    for (size_t i=0; i<iSize; ++i) {
        result[i] = static_cast<char>(tolower(result[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you *really* want the function to modify the input string in-place and return a reference to that input, you need the following. Note the differences in the first line. Also, note that your original string can't be const if you want to modify it:

```
string& tolower(string& str) {
    size_t iSize = str.size();
    for (size_t i=0; i<iSize; ++i) {
        str[i] = static_cast<char>(tolower(str[i]));
    }
    return str;
}
```

However, I'd say that the second version is inferior, and you should stick with the first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But the problem is somewhere else.
Not only here, but everywhere I try to assign some to a reference that was passed from different cpp file, that gives me segmentation fault. But if the reference is passed from same cpp file its ok.

why passing reference to different cpp file causes the segmentation fault in android-ndk?

Comment: I've used gnustl_static.
It doesn't support reference passing from one shared library to another shared library and was giving segmentation fault.
This works when they are in the same library.